# Yellow Spots on Coconut Palm - Seeking Advice

Tags: diagnosis, indoors, palm

Our Coconut Pal is getting yellow spots.

We are encountering a problem with our Coconut Palm; it's developing yellow spots. I researched similar issues and found a discussion about brown spots on a coconut palm [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/55195/why-is-my-coconut-palm-getting-brown-spots), but the symptoms don't seem to match. The yellow spots on our palms seems to be spread more **uniformly** and there are more of them.

Here's some detailed information about the plant and its care environment:

- **Planting Time:** Planted two months ago.
- **Environmental Conditions:**

  - Average Temperature: 23°C
  - Average Humidity: 46%
- **Watering Schedule:** Once every two weeks, with about ~5 liters each time.
- **Drainage:** Adequate drainage in place.
- **Soil Type:** Specialized soil for indoor plants.
- **Fertilizers:** No fertilizers used.
- **Sunlight Exposure:** Mostly indirect sunlight, but occasionally it receives direct sunlight.
- **Pot Details**: Size: 102 liters (40cm x 40cm x 100cm)
- **Plant Details:**

  - Height: 1 meter
  - Co-habitants: Other plants are sharing the pot.
  - Recent Changes: None.
- **Other:** I suspect there were Mealybugs on it a week ago - I've cleaned them using soapy water.

Given these details, I haven't been able to identify the cause of the yellow spots. Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated.

This is how it looks like (with zoomed in one of the yellow spots):
[image: Leaves with close-up of a yellow spot with a brown edge]

I hope it's not too late to make it happy again...

Comment: More direct sun will not hurt. I'd water 1 liter a week, not 5 at a time.

Comment: Not sure I can do anything WRT sun. But thanks for watering tip...

Comment: Does it drop below freezing on the Mediterranean? Put it outside when it's mild.

Comment: The pot is quite large and heavy so no easy way to move it outside...